# What is the proper way to feed this function as input and test if my statement is true?

Tags: expression-test, proof

$f(S)$ = {$n∈N$: $n=m²$ for $m∈S$}

$S$ = $1,2,3$

Square each element in S

Now, $S= 1, 4, 9$

All elements in $S$ are counting from $1$ to $N$. In this case $N=3$

1. $f(S)$ = {$n∈N$: $n=m²$ for $m∈S$}
2. $total~sum~of~S$ = $14$
3. Decide if $total~sum~of~S$ is always < $2^N$ for every possible given $N$.

My assumption is that the $total~sum~of~S$  will never have an exponential magnitude. I know this wouldn't work when $N$ is $4$ because $2^4$=$16$ and the  $total~sum~of~S$ would be greater. 
But I'm referring to the value not being exponential in worst-case input for $S$.

### Question

How would I be able to test my assumption is true on wolfram-site?

Comment: Presumably, you are aware of the [square pyramidal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number)?

Comment: @J.M. Re-discovered them while I was working on trying to reduce Exact Cover into Subset-sum during computer-science hobby.

Comment: With that in mind, look at the result of `Reduce[(n + 1) (2 n + 1) n/6 < 2^n && n > 0, n, Integers]`.

Comment: @J.M. Anyway, for it to output True/False?